# Draw graphical elements with different color in OpencvJS?

Tags: javascript, opencv, colors

I am trying to draw different graphical elements using Opencv.js and I am trying to use different colors for different elements. It seems that the only color I get displayed is white no matter what parameters I set to the Scalar object that represents the color. Any ideas on how I should go about solving this?

e.g
`cv.line(mat, new cv.Point(midPoints[1][0], midPoints[1][1]), new cv.Point(midPoints[3][0], midPoints[3][1]), new cv.Scalar(188, 255, 0), 3);`

The above code draws a line but it's white when it should be some kinf of green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not drawing over a GRAY image?

```
input_image = cv2.imread("./docs/images/test_image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.namedWindow("RGB Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("Gray Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

line_in_color = cv2.line(input_image, (10, 300), (800, 300), (188, 255, 0), 15)
line_in_gray = cv2.line(gray_image, (10, 300), (800, 300), (188, 255, 0), 15)
    
cv2.imshow("RGB Image", line_in_color)
cv2.imshow("Gray Image", line_in_gray)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result of the above code:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The image itself is colored. However the resulting line is always white no matter what values I put in.

Comment: @Vlad Could you check if this work?? cv.line(mat, new cv.Point(20, 160), new cv.Point(100, 160), [0, 0, 255, 255], 10)

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the alpha channel, however I couldn't get it to work before. Now it worked. Thank you.